# Oracle 19c Incremental Statistics Strange Behaviour

Tags: database, oracle, statistics, partition, oracle19c

I have a large table with 2100 partitions. Data is loaded into this table every day, but I don't know exactly which partitions the data will go into. However, on average, about 6-7 partitions receive data each day.

I'm attempting to obtain incremental statistics on this table. However, Oracle consistently collects statistics on all partitions of the table. The expected behavior is for Oracle to gather statistics only on the partitions with changed data.

Furthermore, when I attempt to collect statistics on the same table without performing any operations, it still collects statistics on all partitions, even when there is no data loading.

I have other similar tables where there are no issues. This behavior is unique to one table. Below, I'm sharing some of the parameters I've configured for this table and how I'm collecting statistics. Is there another parameter I should investigate to prevent this behavior? Or, why might Oracle be exhibiting this behavior?

```
APPROXIMATE_NDV_ALGORITHM  ->HYPERLOGLOG
INCREMENTAL_STALENESS      ->USE_STALE_PERCENT
GRANULARITY                ->PARTITION
INCREMENTAL                ->TRUE
PUBLISH                    ->TRUE




 dbms_stats.gather_table_stats
                            (
                              ownname => 'TABLE_OWNER',
                              tabname => 'TABLE_NAME',
                              estimate_percent => 1,
                              degree =>  32
                            );
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that the following have to be set for incremental stats to work:

```
GRANULARITY => 'AUTO'
INCREMENTAL => TRUE
PUBLISH => TRUE
ESTIMATE_PERCENT => DBMS_STATS.AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE
APPROXIMATE_NDV_ALGORITHM => 'HYPERLOGLOG'
INCREMENTAL_LEVEL => 'PARTITION'
```

The key thing that's messing you up is probably `granularity` and `estimate_percent`. These must be `AUTO` because Oracle will gather at the table level once and then gather partitions as needed, and it has to be able to make this determination itself. Increasingly Oracle requires these both to be `AUTO` to do enable advanced statistics gathering capabilities. You should set these at the table level with `dbms_stats.set_table_prefs`, then when you call gathering, provide no options other than identifying the table.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. However, I've tried it as you suggested, but statistics are still being collected in the same way. I've made numerous attempts.

Comment: @user3646666 - Have you deleted stats to start fresh, gathered as I show above (first time will be a full gather of all partitions), then loaded data into a new partition and then regathered? You can't test it without populating or significantly changing a partition as part of the test. Also keep in mind that incremental stats is not the same as gathering only on recent partitions. Oracle has always done that based on staleness which is driving by `dba_tab_modifications`. Incremental calculates *global* stats with approximations without having to do a global scan.

Comment: @user3646666 - are you checking `dba_tab_col_statistics.notes` for 'HYPERLOGLOG ' ? You can also check for synopses by querying `SYS.WRI$_OPTSTAT_SYNOPSIS_HEAD$` though you'll have to join it to `dba_objects`. Ultimately what you're looking for is `dba_tab_col_statistics` at the table level (not the partition level) to show updated low_value/high_value/num_distinct/last_analyzed even when a gather only hit one partition. That's incremental stats. Also `dba_tab_statistics.num_rows` where `partition_name is null` (global table level) should increase with new partitions being added and gathered

Comment: " Have you deleted stats to start fresh, gathered as I show above (first time will be a full gather of all partitions), then loaded data into a new partition and then regathered?" 

I have done it. There is no problem now. Thank you !